# I am losing my place in the world

Tags: riddle

Glory to the Pokemon fliers- I am second only to their successor (not by any other name).

The first was replaced by a new model, the second's son went down in glory. The third will be me.

I lord over those of the sea, but I cannot speak as they do.

You all loved her more than me.

Who am I?

---

(It seems like folks are barking up the wrong tree, so I'll clarify- I'm looking for a person, not a Pokemon)

Comment: Is it a pokemon?

Comment: @KevinLiang I suppose that's up for you to decide

Answer (score 2):

Glory to the Pokemon fliers- I am second only to their successor (not by any other name).

> You are flying pokemon

The first was replaced by a new model, the second went down in glory. The third will be me.

> You are one of the 3rd generation

I lord over those of the sea, but I cannot speak as they do.

> You can't speak in human language

You all loved her more than me.

> You comes in couple, but you think that peoples find your mate more interesting
> I can't think any other than **Latios**

Comment: Good effort, but no. The clues are fairly specific, and a correct answer will fit them more closely than this

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are

> Mewtwo

Glory to the Pokemon fliers- I am second only to their successor (not by any other name).

> Can fly, is *second* and has two in his *name* (*successor* of Mew).

The first was replaced by a new model, the second went down in glory. The third will be me.

> Few possibilites here. If first is mew, second is mewtwo and third is mewtwo post-memory wipe (either the one of his or everyone elses). Could also refer to robotic mew that was destroyed.

I lord over those of the sea, but I cannot speak as they do.

> Is powerful enough to rule over other pokemon & possesses an ability that can sap their powers. Also communicates (speaks) using telepathy.

You all loved her more than me.

> The weakest match... Might refer to mew again for being pink and lovable.It could also be dr. Fujis now deceased daughter amber (clone) whose death distressed mewtwo greatly (and led to his memory being wiped).

Comment: Mm, not quite. Maybe I should clarify things a bit, what with everyone going Pokemon crazy recently...

Answer (score 0):

I will take a big shot, though I am a bit late:

You are

> Absalom from the Bible.

Glory to the Pokemon fliers- I am second only to their successor (not by any other name).

> Absalom tried to betray his father, King David, by gathering the people of Israel to side him, hoping to become king himself. Pokemon are the followers.

The first was replaced by a new model, the second went down in glory. The third will be me.

> Absalom was the 3rd son in the family.

I lord over those of the sea, but I cannot speak as they do.

> Israel was located in the "sea" of beautifulness, which was The Lush Land of Canaan

You all loved her more than me.

> Absalom had a beautiful sister named Tamar.